# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I would like to understand why the float function doesn't mix with the strip method.
I removed .strip() and it works. I initially added it in case the user adds space to the price.

Could somebody explain this error message, please?

Where the ERROR message appears:

```
user_update_price = float(input(f"\nWhat is the price of {user_update_input}: ")).strip()
```

Full piece of code:

```
def product_update(product_list):
    core.function_clear()
    product_view(product_list)

    user_update_id = int(input("\nEnter 0 to cancel. Please enter an ID to update the product: "))
    if user_update_id == 0: 
        return
    user_update_input = input("\nEnter 0 to cancel. What is the new product's name? ").strip()
    if user_update_input.strip() == "0":
        return

    current_product = search(user_update_id, product_list)
    user_update_price = float(input(f"\nWhat is the price of {user_update_input}: ")).strip()
    print("\n")

    if user_update_input == '':
        user_update_input = current_product["product_name"]
    if user_update_price == '':
        user_update_price = current_product["price"]

    update_sql = "UPDATE products SET product_name = %s, price = %s WHERE product_id = %s"
    update_value = (user_update_input.title(), user_update_price, user_update_id)
    connectdb.cursor.execute(update_sql, update_value)
    connectdb.connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The float datatype does not support .strip() since that function can only be used on strings. Instead of applying .strip() after converting to float, apply it to the input string itself.

Try:

```
user_update_price = float(input(f"\nWhat is the price of {user_update_input}: ").strip())
```

This should fix the error.